# Import XML to Excel, to date conversation issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml

I need to import XML files to Excel book, but got one issue: Excel convert some number values to date. 
It happens when numbers are separated with dot or hyphen. The "dot problem" is solved (i changed system separator to comma), but hyphen still makes trouble.

**Example:**
XML file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order>
    <Head>
        <OrderCode>ZWA00013819</OrderCode>
        <DateOfShipment>20181231</DateOfShipment>
        <OrderType>LA </OrderType>
    </Head>
    <Detail>
        <Article>5526-02</Article>
        <QuantityPC>30</QuantityPC>
        <PackType>ut</PackType>
        <DateExpiry>26.12.2019</DateExpiry>
    </Detail>
</Order>
```

[image: Import result screenshot]

first row - standard import, second - import to row in text format.
In both cases excel convert it to date, but i need to keep the number ("5526-02") instead.
Could someone please help with this problem?
I need to find the way to keep values in the same format as they shown in xml file, desirable without modifying original file.

Comment: Using the Data -> Import path, you should be able to specify the format of your column by clicking edit on the bottom of the import wizard, right click the column header to change the column data type (try Text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the column datatype on import before finalizing the load.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're pleased with the solution please consider marking it answered so I can get those nerdpoints :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this thorough answer!